# dataTaskWithURL's completionHandler only called when request fails

Tags: swift, delegates, closures, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I need a NSURLSession with a delegate because I have to implement its

```
public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {}
```

delegate method for loading my own CA cert.

I also want to call `dataTaskWithURL` **with** a `completionHandler` because I get the `completionHandler` as a closure-parameter in the method that I make the call.

```
public func call(hostName:String, completion: (responsedata : NSData?, response : NSURLResponse?, error : NSError?) -> Void){

    let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 8;
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:"https://myhost.com/call")

    session.dataTaskWithURL(requestURL!, completionHandler: completion).resume()
}
```

The problem is that the `completionHandler` only gets called if the request times out or fails. If it succeeds, it never gets called. Does anyone know why?

My completionHandler code:

```
call("myhost.com",  completion: {
        (responsedata : NSData?, response : NSURLResponse?, error : NSError?) in
        var newConnectionStatus: Bool
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse{

            if error == nil {
                if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
                {
                    newConnectionStatus = true
                }
                else
                {
                    newConnectionStatus = false
                }
            }
            else{
                newConnectionStatus = false
            }
        }else{
            newConnectionStatus = false
        }

        if newConnectionStatus != scpGlobalVariables.sharedInstance().currentConnectivityStatus{
            scpGlobalVariables.sharedInstance().currentConnectivityStatus = newConnectionStatus
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ConnectionStateChangedNotification", object: self, userInfo: ["connectivityStatus":NSNumber(bool: newConnectionStatus)])

        }

        if newConnectionStatus == true{
            sleep(5)
            self.runConnectionChecker()
        }else{
            sleep(0);
            self.runConnectionChecker()
        }


    })
```

Only times when the completionHandler gets called is if `response` and `responsedata` is nil

Comment: How do you know it's not being called on successful completion? Can you post the code of your completion handler?

Comment: @Michael, because I've waited for many minutes to see if it gets called (using debugger), but it doesn't happen. My breakpoint is at `var newConnectionStatus: Bool`

Comment: Just guessing, but since you're providing a delegate, maybe it's calling delegate methods instead of the completion handler? The doc doesn't say the completion handler is only called if the delegate is nil, but it might be worth investigation.

Comment: @Michael, unfortunately, that seems to be true. I hoped that there is a different way...